# Products disappeared from the category page after adding Multi Vendor Marketplace For Virtuemart - Joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, marketplace

So, before i added "Multi Vendor Marketplace For Virtuemart - Joomla" the products would show on the page and on the category page that the product was, after i added it they're still on the main page that shows all products but they don't show on the category that they are.

There's some prints of me adding a new product to show what i really mean.

1. I defined the Name and the Categories and checkmarked "Published" [Screen cap 1](https://prnt.sc/f8g863)
2. I defined the Stock, Low Stock Notification and Availability Date [Screen cap 2](https://prnt.sc/f8g8a9)
3. Product saved successfully [Screen cap 3](https://prnt.sc/f8g8lb)
4. Just to guarantee [Screen cap 4](https://prnt.sc/f8ga4f)
5. Yeah, it's on the main page "Men's" category, don't mind the 2 stars [Screen cap 5](https://prnt.sc/f8g9al)
6. It isn't on the men's category [Screen cap 6](https://prnt.sc/f8g9l5)
7. neither the accessories category [Screen cap 7](https://prnt.sc/f8g9qn)

Keep in mind that i'm a beginner with joomla.

Comment: Could you please add some [MVCEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of each step / the problem as a whole?

Comment: You might want to delete this question here on StackOverflow and ask it on [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) instead to target Joomla experts more specifically.